# stack contour plot in R

Tags: r, data-structures, plot

I have two different matrices (same x and y axis) which a plot as contour plots contour (x,y,z). I would like to figure out how to stack both matrix into a single plot in R.

I've been trying to use the as.layer function but it doesn't work

```
heteroplot <- contour(a[,1],t(a[,1]),nlevels=7,heterocov^2,col="green",xlab="ppm",ylab="ppm",bty="n")

homocov <- contour(a[,1],t(a[,1]),nlevels=7,cova^2,col="red",xlab="ppm",ylab="ppm",bty="n")

as.layer(homocov,x.same = TRUE, y.same = TRUE)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, if I've understood correctly, using the `add` argument to `contour()`. For example:

```
x <- -6:16
y <- x
z1 <- outer(x, sqrt(abs(x)), FUN = "/")
z2 <- outer(x, abs(x), FUN = "/")
contour(x, x, z1)
contour(x, x, z2, add = TRUE, col = "red") ## overlay second contour
```

which gives:

[image: overlaid contours]

Not sure where the `as.layer` function comes from...?

Comment: Hi, It worked just fine, thanks a lot!!! the as.layer comes function comes from latticeExtra package.

Comment: I suspected as much, @Marcelo - you can't (easily) mix base graphics (such as `contour()`) with grid graphics used by Lattice and ggplot2. If the answer solves your Q, do you want to accept it (hit the big tick) so others with a similar problem know it was resolved?